# Add count of nodes from path to each result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (t:thing{id:'c4474c0c3bb2f46d21156c456a1b9403'})-[:`REWARDED`]->(r)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:`SUPPORTS`]->(e)
RETURN t,r,u
```

Which looks exactly like what I wan't to get (http://note.io/Mgxabp), but I only need the reward nodes (r) and the count of users (u) per reward.

I've tried many queries but mostly I get 2 reward nodes, both with a count of 2 users.

UPDATE:
I added an example in the Neo4J console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ojfa0i

Comment: Please upload a picture with node labels and if possible a better explanation of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. http://note.io/Mgxabp I try to get a Result like Reward-Node1, 2 and Reward-Node2, 0. Cause the first Reward has 2 backers and the second none. I need the reward as node and a user count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to your graph [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ojfa0i)

Try this query:

```
MATCH (t { entity: "thing" })-[:HAS_REWARD]->(r) 
OPTIONAL MATCH r<-[BACKED]-(u)-[:SUPPORTS]->(t) 
RETURN r AS reward,count(u) AS users,collect(u) AS usernodes
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of people/backers per reward you could use:

```
MATCH (t)-[:REWARD | BACKED]->(r) 
RETURN r, count(t)
```

If you only want to know how many people got the reward then you could use:

```
MATCH (t)-[:REWARD | BACKED]->(r) 
WHERE t.entity="person"
RETURN DISTINCT r, count(t)
```

And you could further specify the person you want, with `WHERE t.id="..."`

I recreated you graph in the [neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/jzmtse), where you can try the queries I have here.